# Discrepancies in mathematical definitions.

Tags: soft-question, big-list

> What are some examples where there is a discrepancy in the mathematical definition of a term?

For example :

$\bullet$ Isosceles triangle: "exactly two sides are equal" or does it say "minimum two sides are equal"?

$\bullet$ Binomial Coefficient: $ {n \choose r} a^r \cdot b^{n-r}$ or $ {n \choose r} a^{n-r} \cdot b^r$

Are there any other such examples?

Comment: There is no discrepancy. For example, since $a+b=b+a$ in the binomial theorem, we have two expressions, which are of course equal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that's true, but in the edit, the same value of $r$ gives two different terms.

Comment: Now the terms are indeed different, but the binomial coefficient is only $\binom{n}{r}$. So there is no discrepancy for the definition of a binomial coefficient.

Comment: So should it be binomial term then?

Comment: It seems to me that by "discrepancy" you really just mean "ambiguity", in other words terms whose definitions are not entirely agreed upon. For example some people use $\mathbb N$ to include zero and some not.

Comment: Yes, I do mean ambiguity.

Comment: Some use countable to include finite, some don’t; also, some say dihedral group $D_n$ has $n$ elements, some $2n$

Comment: Some ambiguities come from the fact that names differ from a country to another ; for example, "arithmetico-geometric" sequence is used for the product of an arithmetic and a geometric sequence in the US, and mean a sequence given by a relationship $u_{n+1}=au_n+b$ four some constants $a$ and $b$ in some other countries, like France.

Comment: A comma is used to separate thousands in US but as a decimal point in Europe.

Comment: according to some authors, a ring must have a multiplicative identity, but not according to others

Comment: in some contexts, a linear relationship is $y=mx+b$; in others, $y=mx$

Comment: some use the symbol $\subset$ to mean subset; others use that symbol to mean proper subset

Comment: some multiply permutations right to left; others, left to right

Comment: for the complex inner product, some take the first argument to be conjugate-linear  and the second to be linear, while others do the reverse

Comment: some use "range" to mean image; others use "range" to mean codomain

Answer (score 3):

There are notations and terms in mathematics that have different conventions.  For example, to some $\Bbb N$ is {$1,2,3,...$}, whereas to others $\Bbb N$ is {$0,1,2,3,...$}.   For another example, some say a set is countable if there is an *in*jective function from it to $\mathbb N$, whereas others say it has to be *bi*jective.  For another example, to some the dihedral group $D_n$ has $n$ elements, and to others it has $2n.$  In all of these cases, a writer using these should indicate which convention is being followed.

Comment: I would phrase the ambiguity with countably as "Some say a set is countable if it an injective function exists from it to $\mathbb{N}$ others say it has to be bijective.

Comment: Sincere question for @QthePlatypus:   Why would you phrase it differently from the way I did?

Comment: The way you phrase it sounds like the finite sets are arbitrarily thrown into the class of countable.  But saying it has an injection into the naturals gives a single rule and suggests how you would prove that something is uncountable.

Comment: I guess I was trying to be less technical by saying some say a set is countable if it has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N,$ whereas to others it also includes the case where the set is finite, but I have edited based on the feedback