# Minimum n for which $2020^n+1$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I wish to find the minimum value of Positive integer $n$ for which $2020^n+1$ is a prime number.
Since $n$ cannot be odd or of the form $2^jK$, therefore $n$ must be of the form $2^k$. How to proceed further?

Comment: Does $n=0$ count?

Comment: @Levent n must be a natural number

Comment: How do we even know that there is such an $n$? As you say it is enough to check powers which are powers of $2$, but that doesn't guarantee the existence of an $n$ for which it is prime. This alone doesn't have a proof : all you can do is check these numbers for primality, and be happy when you get your first hit.

Comment: "Does n=0 count?"  $1$ is not a prime number.

Comment: @fleablood: No, but if $n = 0$, then $2020^n+1 = 1+1 = 2$ is a prime number.  It's still sort of a cop-out, though.

Comment: @SagarSodhani:  According to [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264198/discrepancies-in-mathematical-definitions), $0$ is a natural number; according to others, it is not

Comment: Oops.... that was embarrassing.

Comment: Okay. I’ve edited the question to say positive integer instead of a natural number to avoid ambiguity. Thanks.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon : So there is no other way to either prove or disprove this instead of combing through all the powers of 2?

Comment: @SagarSodhani Any method to prove it has not been discovered yet, let us put it that way : hence we don't even know if it is true or not that such an $n$ exists. So your best bet is to comb, and since you don't have infinite time, you never know when you're getting the answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I spoke with a friend last night. The Miller Rabin "test of compositeness" is well suited to this. As we suspect that the expression above is always composite, it is reasonable to investigate, instead of patterns among small prime factors, patterns in MR "witness" numbers, which requires nothing more that the powermod algorithm  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Mathematical_concepts  I was not sure, but when MR produces a witness, that is a proof that the number being tested is composite. What if there is a fixed number that  serves as a witness?

Comment: @WillJagy That is something I did not know about, thank you for informing me! But my programming skills are poor so I hope someone else takes this task on.

Comment: Numbers of this form could easily be proven prime with the $p-1$-method, if they are not too large. But here, we can have bad luck that the smallest prime is out of reach. If upto $n=2^{20}$ no prime occured, hope is already small to find a prime.

Comment: The genealized fermat numbers $a^{2^n}+1$ have been tested upto very high bases apparently upto $n=20$. According to the smallest bases $a$ , such that we get a prime (OEIS) , upto $n=20$ , we get no prime for $a=2020$ upto $n=20$. Hence the smallest possibility is $$2020^{2^{21}}+1$$ which has already $$6\ 931\ 825$$ decimal digits.

Comment: Upto $n=12$ , the compositeness for $a=2020$ has already be shown and for $13\le n\le 20$ , the smallest base $a$ exceeds $10^4$

Answer (score 3):

This first bit is a tiny part of Miller-Rabin. It is just checking, as in Fermat's LITTLE theorem, whether $2^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n.$ It is not for these first few values of $n =1 + 2020^{\left( 2^k  \right)} \; . \; \;$  It appears that I made $k$ equal to "count" minus one.

==============================================

```
Tue Sep 15 06:07:06 PDT 2020

 count 1 n or n % 1000000:   2021
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  661
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  385
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  883
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  1046


 count 2 n or n % 1000000:   4080401
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  392873
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  696939
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  415506
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  201073


 count 3 n or n % 1000000:   16649664160001
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  7948
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  521537
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  312595
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  917808


 count 4 n or n % 1000000:   277211316640788505600000001
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  65536
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  967296
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  890625
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  778611


 count 5 n or n % 1000000:   76846114073719506240708648109081231360000000000000001
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  419286
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  63545
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  602437
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  663872


 count 6 n or n % 1000000:   1
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  928344
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  551554
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  527082
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  23082


 count 7 n or n % 1000000:   1
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  808526
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  595382
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  982181
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  749767


 count 8 n or n % 1000000:   1
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  959018
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  26848
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  768460
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  848154


 count 9 n or n % 1000000:   1
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  747693
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  986246
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  31483
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  323871


 count 10 n or n % 1000000:   1
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  210163
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  581207
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  920926
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  393805


 count 11 n or n % 1000000:   1
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  70595
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  593199
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  971165
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  587666


 count 12 n or n % 1000000:   1
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  408027
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  331817
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  817564
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  571971
```

=============================================

It took a while to finish 13

```
 count 13 n or n % 1000000:   1
  2^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  447838
  4^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  192814
  5^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  108756
  101^(n-1) mod n or that % 1000000:  270600
```

==========================================

```
int mp_PrimeQ( mpz_class  i)
{
  if ( i <= 0 ) return 0;
  else if ( i == 1 ) return 1;
  else return  mpz_probab_prime_p( i.get_mpz_t() , 50 );
} // mp_PrimeQ

int mp_CompositeQ( mpz_class  i)
{
 
   return !(mp_PrimeQ(i));
} // mp_PrimeQ
```

=======================================================================

```
Sun Sep 13 11:56:09 PDT 2020

0   2021 = 43  47
 PrimeQ  0 

1   4080401 = 13 281  1117
 PrimeQ  0 

2   16649664160001 = 325217  51195553
 PrimeQ  0 

3   277211316640788505600000001 = 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

4   76846114073719506240708648109081231360000000000000001 = 1153  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

5    =  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

6    = 257 11777  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

7    = 638977  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

8    = 15361 51713  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

9    = 19457  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

10    =  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

11    =  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

12    =  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0 

13    = 65537 163841  cdot mbox{BIG} 
 PrimeQ  0
```

Comment: so far no prime?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner so far none, plus not much pattern in the small prime factors, other than some are themselves Fermat primes. It is stuck on line 14; I do not

Comment: If the table [here](http://yves.gallot.pagesperso-orange.fr/primes/results.html) is correct, there should be no primes at least up to line 15.

Comment: line 13: 27,078 digits not prime. Used Mathematica

Comment: $2020^{2^{13}}+1$ has $27078$ digits

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi $2020^{2^{13}}+1$ has 27078 digits and is not prime, as well as $2020^{2^{14}}+1$. Using Wolfram Mathematica. Quite tiring, tbh...

Comment: @Raffaele if you scroll down within the computer output section of my answer, you can see two small prime factors at line 13. One of them is a Fermat prime, which is suggestive. Perhaps there is a proof that the number being investigated is always composite; a next direction to look at might be writing a Miller-Rabin test ( for me, C++ with GMP) with lots of print statements,  see if we can predict a "witness"  in this problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Mathematical_concepts

Comment: A proof that $2020^{2^n}+1$ is never prime is almost surely out of reach. If we can trust the OEIS-entry with the smallest bases (see above) , there is no prime for $n\le 20$. Candidates are $n=21,22,23$ , in each case no prime factor with less than $16$ digits, but still the numbers have very little chance to be prime.

Comment: @Peter  could you please repeat the OEIS link, I cannot find it.

Comment: @Peter added output at the beginning, this time just $2^{n-1} \pmod n$  where $n = 1 + 2020^{\left( 2^k \right)}$

Comment: @WillJagy https://oeis.org/A056993