# Legendre symbol for (2/p)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

I'm reading a proof that
$$
(2/p) = (-1)^{\frac{p^2 -1}8}
$$
for odd primes $p$. I follow the proof upto and including this line:
[image]

Which follows from the fact
$$p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8 \implies \frac{p^2 -1}8 \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \tag{1} $$
and similarly
$$p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 8 \implies \frac{p^2 -1}8 \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \tag{2}. $$

However to convince myself of these last facts I had to write $p = 8k +1$ and go from there etc. Is there an easy way to (1) and (2), or at least a way to show it without leaving modular arithmetic?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but several of the proofs in this course involve similar deductions and I'd rather know the simpler route, thanks!

Comment: A shortcut is to show $p^2\equiv 1\mod 16$ , if $p\equiv \pm1\mod 16$ or $p\equiv \pm9\mod 16$. Try to find an analogue proof for the second case.

Comment: If $8|p\pm1$, then $16|(p\pm1)(p\mp1)$, but if $16\nmid (p-1)(p+1)$, then $8\nmid p\pm1$

Comment: @Peter:  I think you'd be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3824780/minimum-n-for-which-2020n-1-is-prime)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner In factordb, the smallest unknown case is $n=2^{14}$, but if I understood the answers right, the exponents upto at least $2^{15}$ have also been checked. Is that right ?

Comment: @Peter: Thanks thats what i was looking for, I see how it would work in the second case too. Am i right in saying the general fact we're using is that $a \equiv b \pmod m \implies a \equiv b, b + m, b + 2m, ... $ or $b+(n-1)m \bmod nm$?

Comment: @Peter:  I think so

Comment: @RedGrassrex:  cf. [mod distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059752/mod-distributive-law-factoring-bmod-ab-bmod-ac-ab-bmod-c/2059937#2059937)