# The proper symbol to denote proper subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

> **⊂ and ⊃ symbols**
>
> Some authors use the symbols ⊂ and ⊃ to indicate subset and superset respectively; that is, with the same meaning and instead of the symbols, ⊆ and ⊇
>
> Other authors prefer to use the symbols ⊂ and ⊃ to indicate proper (also called strict) subset and proper superset respectively; that is, with the same meaning and instead of the symbols, ⊊ and ⊋.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset

Whether we should use ⊂ or ⊊ to represent the proper (strict) subset? Which symbol have more use?

(Folks, most of the time I work with languages. I'm not a mathematician at all. Just in case.)

Comment: As Wikipedia says, some authors use one and some use the other.  Both are quite common.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264198/discrepancies-in-mathematical-definitions?r=SearchResults)

Comment: I like using $\subset$ for subset or equal. I find that I rarely need to talk about proper subsets. You can use whatever you want as long as you make it clear to the reader what you mean.

Comment: To be *absolutely* clear, can use $\subseteq$ to mean proper/equal subset and $\subsetneq$ to mean proper subset and never use $\subset$. *No* ambiguity.  But different authors will do different things.  If I see $\subset$ with no indication what which meaning they are using and no context indicating it *must* be a proper subset, I would assume is proper or equal.  ... If I were dictator of the world I would declare $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ are exactly the same and authors can use either for style and/or emphasis. And *must* use $\subsetneq$ for proper. But I'm not dictator of the world.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you not use $\subset$ at all, precisely because in current usage it is ambiguous. Use $\subseteq$ and, for proper inclusion, either $\subsetneq$ or $\subsetneqq$.

Comment: Exactly what @MichaelMorrow said, plus that it does not matter which convention is more popular, but it matters most that your reader knows exactly what you mean.