# How to check that given relation is a function?

Tags: functions, modules, relations, absolute-value

If f is defined from set of integers to set of natural numbers,
f(x)=|x|
Then is f a function?
Obviously it's not one-one but is it even a function?
I got confused because 0 belongs to integers and f(0)=0 but 0 does not belong to natural numbers so 0 has no image under f, hence f is not a function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  There are different [conventions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264198/discrepancies-in-mathematical-definitions/3264294#3264294) concerning whether $0\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Would you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether or not $0$ is included in the natural numbers. There are two conventions, one that is all positive integers and one that is all non-negative integers (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number) for more information). If you are taking the natural numbers to not include $0$ then you are correct that $f$ is not a function. This is because a function is a binary relation between two sets that associates every element of the first set to exactly one element of the second set. In your example, the $0$ in your domain is not associated with any element in the second set so it is not a function.

Comment: Specifically, if you consider $0\in\mathbb{N}$, then from the perspective of set theory $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ means that $f$ is a relation from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e., a subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$) in which the first element is unique. So $f = \{\ldots,(-2,2),(-1,1),(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),\ldots\}$.